# How do you calculate the number of connected graphs?

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of node and an array of edges, how do you calculate the number of connected graphs?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us your code snippet and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

- Start at one of the node do the BFS or DFS to get all the nodes connected from this node.
- Now iterate through the node list to find any node which is not included in already,
- do the same procedure on the node. Repeat till all the nodes are visited.
- By now you will have all the graphs in your data.

Comment: Union find will be faster than this, especially for large datasets. Although this will work.

Comment: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find See this for a good explaination of Union Find </a>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union find (you can search it up). Start with all of the nodes as separate sets, then for each edge join the two nodes that the edge connects into the same set. Then check how many different sets there are by going through all the nodes and finding how many different representatives there are.

Comment: +1: But you should mention that is better over dfs/bfs only if you plan to update the graph dynamically. For static graphs, a bfs/dfs is better.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on quasiverse's answer, here's a short pseudo code for it:

make_set(v) creates a new set whose only member is v.

union(x, y) unites the two sets x and y. The representative element for the new set is chosen from one of the two sets

get_representatve(v) returns the representative of the set the given node is a member of.

Find connected components in a graph G = (V, E):

```
foreach vertex v in V:
    make_set(v)

foreach edge (u, v) in E:
    if get_representatve(u) != get_representatve:
         union(u, v)
```

Implementing the necessary functions is an exercise for the reader ;-) Anyway it'll work fine for undirected graphs, but if you want strongly connected components you should look at Tarjan's algorithm.

For parallel implementations there exists afaik no work-efficient deterministic algorithm, but some interesting random ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an algorithm which is linear in the size of the graph, O(|V| + |E|).

```
visited := the empty set
count := 0
for each vertex v in vertices:
    if v not in visited:
        count++
        add v and all nodes reachable from v to visited
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

For undirected graphs, this can be done in O(n) time, with a simple DFS. Here's how:

Define `explore` as a procedure that finds all the nodes that can be reached from a given node. This is just a recursive DFS-like procedure where at each node, you find all the children of that node and push them onto the stack.

To find the answer, start the DFS at any node and initiate the `explore` procedure on that node. Keep an integer(lets say `cc`) and pass it to the `explore` procedure every time it is called. Also, keep a hashmap/dictionary or such that maps `cc` to the corresponding node. At each level of the `explore` procedure, map the current node to `cc` at the moment. Every time the explore procedure is called recursively, pass it the same value of `cc`.

Every time `explore` returns to the DFS loop, increment `cc` and pass that value the next time. Once you are done with the entire DFS, you will have a dictionary that maps each node to it's corresponding connected component number. The value of `cc` at the end of this procedure can give you the number of connected components there are in the graph.

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
function explore(node, graph, cc, map){
    map(currentNode) = cc
    //find all children of current node, and push onto stack. 
    //mark current node as visited
    for i in stack:
        explore(i, graph, cc, map)
}

function DFS{
     int cc = -1
     for node in keysOfGraph:
          if not visited:
              cc++
              explore(node, graph, cc, map)

return cc
}
```

From [Dasgupta Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap3.pdf) (section 3.2.3)